# Passing parameter pack to emplace stl function cause compilation bug

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, variadic-templates

According to the definition of emplace_back, `void emplace_back (Args&&... args);` is a variadic template function. So, I wrote the following:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector2(10,0);
  myvector2.emplace_back(1,2,3,4,5,6);
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
g++ -std=c++0x stlstudy.cc
‘
Internal compiler error: Error reporting routines re-entered.
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
Preprocessed source stored into /tmp/cc7q32tE.out file, please attach this to your bugreport.
```

And the OS alerts:

```
Sorry, Ubuntu 13.04 has experienced an internal error.
```

The `/tmp/cc7q32tE.out` filen is too long to post it here and maybe it will not help. Am I doing something wrong or is compilation bug? I don't get it.

***After the comments and the bug report:***
jrok gives a very good explanation about why this happens. I used gcc 4.7, I reported the bug and I got the following response:

```
Jonathan W***** <redi at gcc dot gnu.org> changed:

           What    |Removed                     |Added
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Known to work|                            |4.8.0

--- Comment #1 from Jonathan W***** <redi at gcc dot gnu.org> ---
Seems to be fixed for 4.8 already.
```

Comment: Well the compiler itself says it's a bug, so most likely it is. You should probably do what it asks you, and report it.

Comment: emplace tries to create a new object of type int with parameters (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6). Int does not have such a constructor.

Comment: Which means the bug is a crash-on-invalid. The compiler crashes instead of giving you a useful error, but it's not like it would compile anyway.

Comment: What version of gcc is this?

Comment: +1 for interesting bug.

Comment: I thought `emplace` was not implemented in 4.7.x?

Comment: @JohnDibling it's actually implemented in 4.6.2. Interestingly, it happily accepts the above code and pushes `6` onto the vector. I would guess it does something like this: `myvector2.push_back((1,2,3,4,5,6));`

Comment: @JohnDibling: It depends on the container. Eg. `vector/unordered_map` have `emplace` in GCC 4.7  but `map` doesn't. Go figure.

Comment: @syam:  I recall reading somewhere they had trouble implementing it specifically for the associative containers, and that's why it's implemented for some containers but not for others.

Comment: Just FYI, if you want to use one statement to add multiple values to a standard container, you may want to look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Internal compiler error is not your fault. Compilers are supposed to give a meaningful diagnostic in case of ill-formed input, not just crash on you.

However, the number and types of arguments of `emplace_back` must match one of the constructors of vector's value type. You have a vector of `int`s, so you can pass at most one argument that either has a matching type or is implicitly convertible to `value_type`.
(You could leave argument list empty - that would construct the object using default constructor).

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.emplace_back(1);   // ok
v.emplace_back(1.0); // ok
v.emplace_back(1, 2); // not ok, there's no constructor for `int` that takes two ints
```

The purpose of `emplace_back` isn't to push multiple elements in the same statement (I got an impression that this is what you expected it to do - I thought the same a while ago) but to construct an element in place, forwarding the arguments to the constructor and avoiding copies).

Gcc 4.8. [does error out](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/), although the error message isn't particulalry helpul.

Comment: You are true, that is what I thought, that "recursively" push back the elements into the container. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: _"so you can only provide one argument"_; You can provide zero arguments too, which is equivalent to `v.push_back( int() );`